# Error message in Command Prompt when installing module

Tags: python, cmd, command-prompt

This is my first attempt at installing an add in for Python. I have extracted the twitter module to a folder within my Python33 directory that I have called 'Plug ins'. I have then navigated to this in Command Prompt and entered the following code that I have found on the Python website:

```
python setup.py install
```

That produced an error that 'python' was not a recognised command. When i removed 'python'a nd just ran:

```
setup.py install
```

I got the error message:

```
Import error: No module named 'setuptools'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install `setuptools`:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#installing-and-using-setuptools

Basically,

- for **Linux**:

  ```
  wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | python
  ```
- for **Windows 7**:

  download and execute [this file](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py).
- for **Windows 8**, execute in PowerShell (as Admin):

  ```
  (Invoke-WebRequest https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py).Content | python -
  ```

Comment: i'm on windows vistam but im assuming that the method for 7 should work? do i have to download setup tools and install it? i've added that piece of code and got the same error message...

Comment: Just right click on the link and download the file and run it, don't copy the code anywhere.

Comment: apologies for being dense, but when i right click on the link i dont have an option to download the contents of the link.

Comment: What browser are you using? In Chrome it is "Save Link As". I believe Firefox also.

Comment: right, sorry yes...at cross purposes with you there, it seems to have installed correctly now. thanks.